# I can't add new icons in CKEditor default toolbar

Tags: wysiwyg

I can't add new icons (tabs) in CKEditor toolbar, in EDITOR APPEARANCE options. Whatever I choose it only gives me default toolbar. I tried all versions. What should I do?

Comment: the icons would depend on the filter being selected as well. so if you have set the icons for Full HTML and you choose filtered html then it would only show that

Comment: No, no. I know that. But, for example, if I set in EDITOR APPEARANCE full toolbar with lot of icons for Full HTML option, when I go to site it still displays only default, basic toolbar although I select Full HTML.

Comment: If you are using the latest ckeditor library, they now do a standard download and a full download. To get all of the missing buttons ensure you have the full library in sites/all/libraries see http://drupal.org/node/1882396#comment-6914682

Answer (score 2):

If you have [jquery_update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) installed and using 1.8 you might also run into javascript errors if you are trying to move toolbar elements around. Temporary setting it to 1.5 (doing my changes and setting it back to 1.8) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the toolbar and add icons manually. To turn off the toolbar go to the admin/config/content/ckeditor/editg and select 'disable' for 'Use toolbar Drag&Drop feature'. I am guessing that the toolbar misbehaves because CKEditor Module imports JQuery UI sortable lib that is already imported once by the core. As result, it causes js fatal errors. I am out of time to verify.